# moving one array into other array for handling ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
  var res =   
         {
          "response": {
            "data": {
              "profilesearchsnippet": [
                [
                  {
                    "profileInfo": {
                      "firstname": "Sundar",
                      "lastname": "v"
                    },
                    "roleInfo": {
                      "defaultphotoid": 94
                    }
                  }
                ],
                [
                  {
                    "profileInfo": {
                      "firstname": "ghg",
                      "lastname": "vbhvh"

                    },
                    "roleInfo": {
                      "defaultphotoid": 171
                    }
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
$scope.profileData = [];
```

I have a response `var res` . I need to pass my defaultphotoid to another request and form URL for displaying the image. which I pushed in `$scope.images` and I need to display all list of images along with respective firstname and lastname. But I couldnt do it. somewhere I am lacking it.

I pushed firstname and lastname in array by creating object in `$scope.profileData`

```
$scope.searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet;

for (var i = 0; i < searchData.length; i++) {
  $scope.profileData.push({
    'fname':searchData[0].profileInfo.firstname,
    'lname':searchData[0].profileInfo.lastname
  });
}
```

The above `$scope.profileData []` has exact values what I am pushing , But I could push the values of images from `$scope.images` into this.

```
$scope.profileData.push({'image': images[i]});
```

what happen in above case is the first array has fname and lname object and second array object has image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
$scope.searchData = res.response.data.profilesearchsnippet;
     for (var i = 0; i < searchData.length; i++){
    $scope.profileData.push({'fname':searchData[0].profileInfo.firstname,'lname':searchData[0].profileInfo.lastname, 'image':''});
}
```

Then:-

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.images.length; i++){
$scope.profileData[i].image = $scope.images[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `push` into an array, it is added as a separate object in the array. If you want the image to be added along with fname and lname, add it in the loop itself like :

```
$scope.profileData.image = images[i];
```

If you already has the `$scope.images` array, You can add the image too in the same for loop you are using to add lName and fName like this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < searchData.length; i++){
 $scope.profileData.push({'fname':searchData[i].profileInfo.firstname,'lname':searchData[i].profileInfo.lastname, 'image':$scope.images[i]});
}
```

Comment: So Do I need to create image key before doing this operation ?

Comment: Do you have all the images in a separate array ? How do you identify the corresponding image link of a profile from profileData ?, based on photoId ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, let me know if that is what you are expecting.